# IP Subnetting /16 into 5 equal parts

Tags: ip-address, subnets

I having a hard time understanding IP subnetting for /16 mask. I went through some tutorials and understood the host part and non-vlsm but with vlsm and dividing into equal parts, is something I am not sure yet. Especially for the below sample, if someone can help me with the output, I will be able to deduce the explanation.

**For this: `10.0.0.0/16`, I have been asked to divide into 5 equal parts**. Based on the tutorials I followed, one of them is this : [IP Subnetting](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html), I came up with these but my mentor says its wrong and I am not sure why.

```
10.0.0.0/18 --- IP Range: 10.0.0.1 ==> 10.0.63.254 (16384 IP addresses)
10.0.64.0/18 --- IP Range: 10.0.64.1 ==> 10.0.127.254 (16384 IP addresses)
10.0.128.0/18 --- IP Range: 10.0.128.1 ==> 10.0.191.254 (16384 IP addresses)
10.0.192.0/19 --- IP Range: 10.0.192.1 ==> 10.0.223.254 (8192 IP addresses)
10.0.224.0/19 --- IP Range: 10.0.224.1 ==> 10.0.255.254 (8192 IP addresses)
```

I am assuming it's incorrect because it's not in equal parts.

I hope someone guides and can provide the correct answer to it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ipcalc` may be of use

Comment: You can't divide a network range into 5 equal parts. The closest you can get is to divide it into 8 equal parts (in this case, they'd be /19s) and then discard 3 of them. BTW, anything that still talks about class A, B, and C networks is hopelessly out of date -- those address classes got thrown out with the transition to CIDR in 1993. They haven't been a thing in nearly three decades!

Comment: Assuming "divide into" does not entail discarding a lot of addresses, you can't do much better than what you have described, so I would ask your mentor why that is wrong and what is meant (and as @GordonDavisson says that reference is hopelessly out of date).

Comment: "Updated:May 21, 2021" :D Cisco indeed insists on being stuck in the early 90's. Their switches also say stuff like "xx.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 32 subnets, 9 masks"

Comment: Even if they would accept splitting into eight /19 blocks and using only five, the question becomes why not split into a few /24 blocks and use only five of those. They'd be equally equal in size as the /19 blocks would be. But then the question becomes, what are you going to do with those blocks, and how large do they need to be for that use...

Comment: This question doesn’t really belong on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.  It might be better on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), or maybe [Super User](https://superuser.com), but don’t repost it on any other site without reading that site’s Tour to see whether it would be on-topic there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to divide 65536 addresses into 5 equal parts, since 65536/5 = 13107.2 and you can't have a "one-fifth address".

Comment: It's worse than that, because you can't have fractional bits in the sunet mask, so a subnet's size can only be a power of two. You could make subnets with 16384 addresses each (=2^14= 65536/4) and/or with 8192 addresses each (=2^13= 65536/8), but nothing in between.